# Can't install bzrlib for mac osx 10.10

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm running mac osx 10.10 with python 2.7.10 installed

I can't install bzrlib with pip or easytools

I don't know what is the problem 
i have a piece of code i want to run it but i can't and it give me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migrate.py", line 249, in <module>
    bzrlib.plugin.load_plugins()
NameError: name 'bzrlib' is not defined
```

What should i install to get this work?

It's very important to me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

bzrlib is the python's library behind bzr, you can install bzr using **homebrew** package manager if you haven't installed homebrew you can do this by simply running this script in your terminal

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

after installing homebrew try to run `brew install bzr` in your terminal.